# Logitech TV Cam for Google TV not available for sdk?

Tags: android, android-camera, google-tv, logitech

Today I tried to access Logitech TV Cam from Logitech Revue, but it is not available

```
numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras()
```

always returns 0, while Logitech Vid HD can access the camera.
Any hints how to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Camera is not supported on Google TV. You should be able to use the [USB host APIs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/host.html) to detect the camera if it is attached through USB. You could also use the same APIs to read the input stream from it. I haven't tried it out myself. I will try it later this week and update here.